# Roleplaying play-by-post game for one

Tags: game-recommendation, adventure-writing, play-by-post, solo

I spent quite some time trying to come up with such concept. By play-by-post I mean some kind of game of fiction, in writing. For the single person. What I'm looking for is some set of rules so that one person could play such game, using only some kind of randomizer like dice or a bash script or something.

Comment: Hi waswld, your question is too vague to fit our standards for [tag:game-recommendation] questions.  Can you narrow it so it can be answered?  I've put it on hold till it's updated.

Comment: Google for "RPG Solitaire Challenge" and "Mythic GM Emulator". You'll find others who have investigated this concept. Those might help you figure out what exactly you'd like to ask, then you can come back here and ask about it.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I've been looking for — some directions on this problem and where there were attempts to solve this. Thanks.